# How to understand this crash? SIGSEGV

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

I get this crash quite often recently, device iPhone 5s, SDk: 9.1

```
Crashed Thread: 6
0   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x19af02578 dispatch_source_cancel (in libdispatch.dylib) + 84
2   CFNetwork                           0x18533ca80 SHTTP2ConnectionCache::_onqueue_removeAllConnections() (in CFNetwork) + 60
3   CFNetwork                           0x18533ca1c ___ZN21SHTTP2ConnectionCache24invalidateAllConnectionsEv_block_invoke (in CFNetwork) + 24
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x19aefd6a8 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib) + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x19af069e4 _dispatch_block_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib) + 540
6   CFNetwork                           0x185307ce4 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) (in CFNetwork) + 36
7   CoreFoundation                      0x185b006cc CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation) + 68
8   CFNetwork                           0x185307bc8 RunloopBlockContext::perform() (in CFNetwork) + 136
9   CFNetwork                           0x185307a88 MultiplexerSource::perform() (in CFNetwork) + 312
10  CFNetwork                           0x1853078b4 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) (in CFNetwork) + 68
11  CoreFoundation                      0x185bd4544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 24
12  CoreFoundation                      0x185bd3fd8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation) + 540
13  CoreFoundation                      0x185bd1cd8 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 724
14  CoreFoundation                      0x185b00ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 384
15  CFNetwork                           0x185399b84 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] (in CFNetwork) + 412
16  Foundation                          0x186b5fc80 __NSThread__start__ (in Foundation) + 1000
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x19b113b28 _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 156
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x19b113a8c _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 0
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x19b111028 thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 4
```

Do you have any ideas on what causes this crash?

Comment: Do you have any NSTimer or RunLoop?

Comment: Can you share some related codebase?

Comment: @JuanCurti Both are used in the app.

Comment: @ystack I don't know where the crash happens, so I can't share the related codebase..

Comment: Some crashs are very difficult to discovery the root cause. See Apple tips: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html and use try/catch blocks and try isolate the flow that cause the problem.